# How to change the value of an int, and recover and use the new value?

Tags: python

While attempting at creating some movement for a ball in a pong game, I have run into a most annoying problem. The value of the x and y coordinate do not want to change (for lack of better words). Maybe this is due to the immutable nature of strings in python, or a misconception I have of the way Python handles variables. Any help would be most welcome :)

```
x_coordinate = 100
y_coordinate = 100

NORTH_EAST = [x_coordinate + 1, y_coordinate - 1]
NORTH_WEST = [x_coordinate - 1, y_coordinate - 1]
SOUTH_EAST = [x_coordinate + 1, y_coordinate + 1]
SOUTH_WEST = [x_coordinate - 1, y_coordinate + 1]
direction = NORTH_EAST

while True:

    print (direction)
    x_coordinate = direction[0]
    y_coordinate = direction[1]
```

Comment: what is the expected result? And what's the code doing now, that's incorrect?

Comment: expected: [101][99] , [102][98] , [103][97]

Comment: now its doing [101][99],[101][99],[101][99]....

Comment: hint: NORTH_EAST is a variable, that has (and always will have) value of [101,99]

Comment: It's worth noting that `CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES` is, by convention, reserved for constants (values that don't change) - use `lowercase_with_underscores` instead.

Comment: Tip: `north_east` and others can be functions of `(x, y)` returning new values, because the new point coordinates depend on the old ones.

Comment: yeah I was thinking of it as a function, silly mistake :( ty for help

Comment: oh and I'll keep in mind the lowerscore convention

Comment: @user2278282 [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is a short document that covers the style conventions for Python - it's worth a quick read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that when you say

```
NORTH_EAST = [x_coordinate + 1, y_coordinate - 1]
```

You construct a list of two values, which are computed and stored at the time. They will not update based on the values of `x_coordinate` and `y_coordinate` changing.

You will need to recalculate the values on each loop to get the behaviour you expect. The easiest way to do this is with a function:

```
directions = {
    "north east": (+1, -1),
    "north west": (-1, -1),
    "south east": (+1, +1),
    "south west": (-1, +1),
}

def new_position(old, direction):
    x, y = old
    dx, dy = directions[direction]
    return x + dx, y + dy

position = 100, 100
direction = "north east"

while True:
    print(position)
    position = new_position(position, direction)
```

Note that where there are linked pieces of data, it's best to store them in a data structure. Here I use a tuple to store the `x` and `y` values together, and a dictionary for the directional data. This means less repetition in your code.

Comment: So it was a flaw in my thinking, how embarrassing. ^O^ thank you very much.